# Logstash output from filebeat. What is 'index' configuration option?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

This is an excerpt taken from filebeat config for logstash output [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/logstash-output.html#logstash-index)

[image]

I'm wondering what does index have to do with logstash.
In my logstash configuration itslef, if I redirect logs to ElasticSearch I believe my logs will be indexed under "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" as the documentation says [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index).

So why is there an option to set `index` for filebeat's logstash output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This option exists because you can use that value in the logstash configuration for the index name as logstash also have an `index` option to set the index name when sending data to elasticsearch.

The `index` option value from filebeat is passed as a metadata field to logstash, and you can configure your `elasticsearch` output in logstash to use this field as the index name.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][beat]}" 
  }
}
```

The default value for the `index` option is the beats name, filebeat, metricbeat, heartbeat and auditbeat for example, but if you set it to `logs-prd` in your beat configuration file for example, logstash will use that value as the index name.

If you send your data to logstash before sending it to elasticsearch, it is always logstash that will set the index name using the `index` option, if you don't set the `index` option, it will use the default value, which is simple `logstash` on newer versions.